# Quiero pasar de una jTable a un jTextField pero mi Tabla es del tipo TableView<Map>. Utilizando JavaFX, Netbeans y Scene Builder con MVC

Tags: netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

Para llenar mi tabla utilizo el sig. código ya que estoy utilizando **phpmyadmin** y tengo una conexión a una Base de Datos.

```
public void llenarTabla(){
    ObservableList<Map> lista = getTodosProductos();
    this.jTableColumNombre.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(colNombre));
    this.jTableColumMarca.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(colMarca));
    this.jTableColumCantidad.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(colCantidad));
    this.jTableColumDescripcion.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(colDescripcion));
    this.jTableListaProductos.setItems(lista);
}
```

Y para obtener los Datos dada la funcion getTodosProductos();

```
private ObservableList<Map> getTodosProductos(){
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM `producto`";
    //Crear una coleccion vacia
    ObservableList<Map> usuariosList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try{
        ConexionBD conexion = new ConexionBD ();
        PreparedStatement consulta = conexion.getConexion ().prepareStatement (sql);
        ResultSet resultSet = consulta.executeQuery ();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Producto productito = new Producto();
            Map<String, Object> coleccion = new HashMap<> ();
            //provedor.setId(Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString("Id")));
            productito.setNombre(resultSet.getString("Nombre"));
            productito.setMarca(resultSet.getString("Marca"));
            productito.setCantidad(resultSet.getInt("Cantidad"));
            productito.setDescripcion(resultSet.getString("Descripcion"));;
            //por cada fila creamos una nueva colección
            coleccion.put(colNombre,  productito.getNombre());
            coleccion.put(colMarca,  productito.getMarca());
            coleccion.put(colCantidad,  productito.getCantidad());
            coleccion.put(colDescripcion,  productito.getDescripcion());
            usuariosList.add(coleccion);
        }
        resultSet.close();
        consulta.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        Mensaje.notificar(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "mysql", "ListarProductosController dice: ", e.getMessage());
    }
    return usuariosList;
}
```

Entonces no se como pasar a mi jTextFieldNombre lo que tiene la columna Nombre

Y esta es la declaracion de mis Columnas y Tabla:

```
@FXML    private TableView<Map> jTableListaProductos;
@FXML    private TableColumn<Producto, String> jTableColumNombre;
@FXML    private TableColumn<Producto, String> jTableColumMarca;
@FXML    private TableColumn<Producto, String> jTableColumCantidad;
@FXML    private TableColumn<Producto, String> jTableColumDescripcion;
```

Comment: Es de un TableView<Map> a una TextField

Comment: quiere poner en las celdas de la columna un nodo textfield  ?